# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sniffers with type [ejb] and type [appclient] should not claim the archive at the same time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, illegalargumentexception

**Environment**: GlassFish 3.0.1, NetBeans 6.9, JDK 6u21

Also tested with GlassFish 3.0.1, NetBeans 6.9.1, JDK 6u22, but results are the same.

**Problem**: Unable to run app-client in an enterprise application (app-client, ejb, war).

The EJB jar has **only Local** interfaces and contains no main methods.

**GlassFish Message**

```
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sniffers with type [ejb] and type [appclient] should not claim the archive at the same time. Please check the packaging of your archive [C:\Users\myUser\.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\applications\fabench-app-client]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.validateSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:221)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:426)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:262)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**NetBeans run message**

```
Building jar: F:\NetBeansProjects\fabench\fabench-app-client\dist\fabench-app-client.jar
dist:
pre-run-deploy:
Distributing F:\NetBeansProjects\fabench\fabench-app-client\dist\fabench-app-client.jar to [GlassFish Server 3]
deploy?path=F:\NetBeansProjects\fabench\fabench-app-client\dist\fabench-app-client.jar&name=fabench-app-client&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3
F:\NetBeansProjects\fabench\fabench-app-client\nbproject\build-impl.xml:716: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**application-client.xml**

This contains only the `<display-name>` tag filled, but `<ejb-ref>` can also be specified with a `<remote>` interface. There is no `<local>` tag, so I guess `app-client` is only able to work with Remote interfaces. Is this true?

What could be the problem here?

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
wheelie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- App-client accesses EJBs via Remote interfaces
- Since GlassFish v3, Remote interfaces has to be packed inside a Java Class Library, so interfaces are distributable.
- App-client has to be inside an enterprise application EAR (but not strictly the same EAR with EJB and WAR).

The tutorial under http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html explains how to create an `app-client`, however it doesn't work for me; there is also a question for that matter: [Unable to run app-client that is accessing an EJB on GlassFish v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145242/unable-to-run-app-client-that-is-accessing-an-ejb-on-glassfish-v3).

Answer (score 1):

Not a Glassfish expert, but it sounds like the jar is being seen as both an ejb jar and an app client jar.  If that's the case, it is not a valid app.  First thing I'd check is to ensure your app client jar does **not** have either:

1. A META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
2. Any classes annotated with @Stateless, @Singleton, @Stateful or @MessageDriven

On the other question, right, application clients are remote clients and by definition cannot talk to beans using their @Local interface.

Comment: Those things are checked: Only a `Main.java` is in the `app-client` project, the ejb project is added to libraries. The EJB has no main methods.

The Remote-Local story is now clear, but damn this still doesn't work :|