# Unable to run app-client that is accessing an EJB on GlassFish v3

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish, application-client

**Environment**: GlassFish 3.0.1, NetBeans 6.9, JDK 6u21

**Problem**: Unable to run app-client that is accessing an EJB

A bugreport can be found under http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183488 with the corresponding tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html . I understand now how the Remote interface has to be in a Java Class Library. I walked through the steps of the tutorial, but still, it does not work.

Errors: http://pastebin.com/k8ARGKbX.

According to http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7700/gjkmx?l=en&a=view, this error message means:

> ACDEPL112 Error attempting to process extensions from the manifest of JAR file {0}; ignoring it and continuing
>
> Cause:
>   The exception listed in the log file was thrown as the server tried to open the JAR file or process the extensions listed in its manifest.
>
> Solution:
>   Make sure the manifest of the JAR file correctly lists the extensions on which the JAR depends.

Doesn't mean too much to me, manifest files contain only `Manifest-Version: 1.0`
, should I add something here? :\

A similar discussion can be found under http://forums.netbeans.org/post-86938.html . I also asked this question at the NetBeans Community Forum http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=33195, and sent an email to the editors.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
wheelie

Comment: which permissions to set on glassfish?

Comment: @jdeveloper I gave full control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to make it work - Windows 7:

- Install GlassFish in root; not in `Program%20Files`.
- Set permissions on Glassfish install folder (Full control).

On Windows XP you don't have to set permissions.